# Disable/Enable a textbox in bootstrap modal form based on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, disabled-input

I have a bootsrap modal form.In that if i click on the radio button,'For All Subjects','Subject' textbox should be in disabled state.Similarly,if I click on radio button 'Specific Subject', 'Subject' textbox should be enabled.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="adminContent">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col s12 m12 l12" style="float: right">
        <button type="button" class="btn  btn-lg"
         data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMasterData" >Add Master</button>
       </div>
      </div> </div>
     
     <div class="modal fade vertical-align-center" id="addMasterData"
      role="dialog" style="width: 500px"; role="dialog"
      data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    
      <div class="modal-dialog ">
       <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">
          <b><font class="font">Add Master</font></b>
         </h4>
         
        </div>
        <form id="mastercreate" action="addConfig" method="post">
    
         <div class="modal-content ">
    
          <div class="modal-body "> 
         
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Subjects:</label> <label class="radio-inline">
           <input type="radio" name="roleSubjectRadio" id="forAllSubjects"
           value="Yes"  >For All Subjects
          </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"
           name="roleSubjectRadio" id="specificFlights"
         value="Specific"  checked>Specific Subject
          </label> <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="specs" name="specs"
           value="">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group" id="subName">
            <label for="createorigin" class="form-control-label"><font >Subject
             Name:</font></label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subNo"
             name="subNo" >
           </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
           onclick="addMaster()">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          
         </div>
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>
    
      </div>
     </div>
```

Please suggest how to do it from javascript.

Comment: What javascript have you tried? Please edit your question with some code so we can see what you have attempted. If you are unable to do this, please point to the web pages that discuss the problem you have, and where you are having problems with them.

Comment: @Phil its working..thanks for d help

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use event handling for radio buttons, you can try below snippet for that. I have written that in jQuery, you can also use JavaScript for the same.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
  if($(this).prop("id")==="forAllSubjects"){
    $("#subNo").prop("disabled","remove");
  } else {
    $("#subNo").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="adminContent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12" style="float: right">
      <button type="button" class="btn  btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMasterData" >Add Master</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
          
<div class="modal fade vertical-align-center" id="addMasterData" role="dialog" style="width: 500px"; role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          <b><font class="font">Add Master</font></b>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <form id="mastercreate" action="addConfig" method="post">
        <div class="modal-content ">
          <div class="modal-body "> 
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="text">Subjects:</label> <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="roleSubjectRadio" id="forAllSubjects" value="Yes"  >For All Subjects
              </label> 
              <label class="radio-inline"> 
                <input type="radio" name="roleSubjectRadio" id="specificFlights" value="Specific" checked>Specific Subject
              </label> 
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="specs" name="specs" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="subName">
              <label for="createorigin" class="form-control-label">
                <font >Subject Name:</font>
              </label> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subNo" name="subNo" >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addMaster()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can do this. Give `onclick="disableSubjectField()"` to the radio buttons:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Subjects:</label> <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="roleSubjectRadio" id="forAllSubjects" value="Yes" onclick="disableSubjectField()" >For All Subjects
  </label> <label class="radio-inline"> 
  <input type="radio" name="roleSubjectRadio" id="specificFlights" value="Specific"  onclick="disableSubjectField()" checked>Specific Subject
  </label> <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="specs" name="specs" value="">
</div>
```

Then write this javascript to disable the Subject input field.

```
function disableSubjectField() {
   if(document.getElementById('forAllSubjects').checked) {
        document.getElementById('subNo').disabled = true;

    }else if(document.getElementById('specificFlights').checked) {
        document.getElementById('subNo').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a click function depends on your library 
lets get from a point you don`t use any library

you should do this : (you can copy past and it will work)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<div class="container" id="adminContent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12" style="float: right">
                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-lg"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMasterData" >Add Master</button>
            </div>
        </div>  </div>

    <div  id="addMasterData"
        role="dialog" style="width: 500px"; role="dialog"
        data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

        <div class="modal-dialog ">

            <div class="modal-content ">
                <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                        <b><font class="font">Add Master</font></b>
                    </h4>

                </div>
                <form id="mastercreate" action="addConfig" method="post">

                    <div class="modal-content ">

                        <div class="modal-body ">   

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Subjects:</label> <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="roleSubjectRadio" id="forAllSubjects"
                            value="true" onclick="radioClicked(this.id)"  >For All Subjects
                        </label> 
                        <label class="radio-inline"> 
                        <input type="radio"
                            name="roleSubjectRadio" id="specificFlights"
                    value="Specific" onclick="radioClicked(this.id)"  checked>
                    Specific Subject
                        </label> <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="specs" name="specs"
                            value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="subName">
                                <label for="createorigin" class="form-control-label"><font >Subject
                                    Name:</font></label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subNo"
                                    name="subNo" >
                            </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                            onclick="addMaster()">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        function radioClicked (me){
        //specificFlights
        //forAllSubjects

            if(me === "forAllSubjects" && document.getElementById("subNo").classList.contains('disabled') === false){
                document.getElementById("subNo").setAttribute("disabled",'disabled');
            }else{
                document.getElementById("subNo").removeAttribute("disabled",'disabled');
            }
        }

    </script>
```